# NullReferenceException when MyViewModel is instanciated with service dependency injection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, service, catel

I try using the best approach to use services in Catel, which is to inject services in the viewmodel's constructor:

```
public MyViewModel(IMessageService msgService)
{
    Argument.IsNotNull(() => msgService);
    this.messageService = msgService;
    //stuff
}
```

Yet when I put arguments in this constructor, my program  throws an NullReferenceException, supposedly at the Argument.IsNoNull line (debugging through Catel's code seems to be a pain). When I remove the argument or the IsNotNull validation, it launches fine.

So I do not receive a IMessageService, msgService is always null.
What am I doing wrong? Missing assembly?

---

**EDIT:**
It seems like the IMessageService type is registered. I manage to get a reference by using ResolveType:

```
messageService = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IMessageService>();
```

So as far as my project is concerned, the problem is solved. But it doesn't answer the original question: why isn't dependency injection working?

Comment: How do you create a `MyViewModel` instance?

Comment: @MrWombat: Oh, interesting question. I indeed did something out of my comfort zone: added a Application.Resources key (named MyWindowVM) in App.xaml pointing to MyViewModel, and referenced it in my window's XAML: `<Window ... DataContext="{StaticResource MyWindowVM}"`. Maybe Catel doesn't like custom names for such references.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to change anything if I name my key as my view model.

Comment: You shouldn't manually handle the data context in Catel. It's all done for you. See the Getting Started guide: https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Getting+started

Comment: @GeertvanHorrik that must be the problem indeed. Yet I had absolutely no VS item templates installed when I installed Catel with Nugget.

Comment: They are online templates. Anyway, just let Catel do its magic and all will work fine.

Comment: It does the magic, but VS's editor doesn't quite like it. My controls keep on being scrambled. I'll settle for WPF controls and no magic on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a *null*, it means the dependency cannot be resolved. If you are using the default *ServiceLocator* of Catel, enable logging to see what's going on under the hood in your application startup:

```
#if DEBUG
    LogManager.AddDebugListener();
#endif
```

You can also check if the type is registered by using this code:

```
var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Default;
serviceLocator.IsTypeRegistered<IMessageService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Argument.IsNotNull("msgService", msgService);
```

In the documentation video they do similar with Argument.ArgumentIsNullOrWhitespace

Comment: Both are the same, doesn't matter much.

Comment: But when I look at the source code on Git, I don't see an method call with one parameter. Ok, I see I must look in this partial class [link] (https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/5234dcf4f66188ab1cc5c35089375a6bccb139fd/src/Catel.Core/Catel.Core.Shared/Argument.expression.cs)

Comment: You have Argument.cs => normal checks and Argument.expression.cs => expression checks. See https://github.com/catel/catel/blob/develop/src%2FCatel.Core%2FCatel.Core.Shared%2FArgument.expression.cs

Comment: Wouldn't change much, I only get the NullReferenceException when msgService is defined, so it is the null reference. This check is only here to point towards this fact.

Answer (score 0):

The code for Argument can be found on [Git](https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/5234dcf4f66188ab1cc5c35089375a6bccb139fd/src/Catel.Core/Catel.Core.Shared/Argument.cs), The usage is correct, i fear you have to check the injection. Try to set a breakpoint in the constructor and go through the code until it reaches the breakpoint.

Are you using a special DI-Framework? Yes - then check the registration/setup otherwise find the code that composes the ViewModel

I've just seen in the [documentation](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Dependency+injection) that the types are set up automatically. Is it possible to create the object-graph for your service (are there any *circular dependencies*, or dependencies that cannot be created due to own dependencies or *not matching constructors*?)

Comment: My program is pretty straigtforward; I have one view and one viewmodel. I installed Catel by Nugget and didn't install any other package AFAIK.